# Drifting output

Tags: power-supply, power

I have an old power supply that still works, got it from tandy when they were closing down it use to power the display unit of car head units, anyways  the output voltage has drifted up from 12 to 22 vdc so i took it apart as you do to find a little pot it there that wasn't right so i replaced it with what i had at hand but the output doesn't change so if you look at the pictures the transistor looks blackened on the board but i cannot find the same to replace it.... what should i do?

RS found it and gave me a replacement https://uk.rs-online.com/web/cpo/3136916/

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/bjt-bipolar-transistors/1686073/

I don't have any of them at hand but i do have  I want its output to be 12vdc like it use to be. I'm guessing it's not regulating itself any more
The pictures are of the power supply

LM317T W994F9505 
P88S68 K3679 01
1C21CH FQN 24N50
1C21CL FQA 24N50
MTP8P10R022
MTP12N10925
T 5K 79015P
831 AN7815
NF820 B20100G

pictures
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h7aVrYnnCxYEgNnTdFzGmcU_3-IrjAjj/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QAjZzo3oWcA6zCelFyhaVl_cgqMN7Aga/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wVt9P0TJSX8mqg_NA6NpAidRibxFAvas/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this a fixed \$12\:\text{V}\$ power supply? I see a fuse, a power switch, a transformer and a circuit board. So I'm guessing "fixed." Also, is there a diode missing there? Regardless, I suspect that the transformer (if working) and the case and fuse casing and switch are the most valuable parts. I'd probably just completely replace the rest of it with a new circuit design.

Comment: What burning? Where?

Comment: If you include the RS model # of the power supply someone may have a better chance of helping. At one time RS would make schematics of their equipment available to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The model number is about the same as the visible PCB number.

Here is a forum that discusses repairing of a Samlex 1203 power supply. The PCB on the page looks nearly identical to yours.

One tricky issue is that the web page is all in German, but not to worry, google translator can take care of that. (Use the translated link below)

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&tab=TT&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mikrocontroller.net%2Ftopic%2F384176

The power supply on this page is a 220/240VAC version, yours may be similar even if the input voltage is different, (likely just the transformer would be different).

There seems to be two slightly different versions of the schematic.  You should be able to verify which one matches by just checking the components.

Another thing I noticed is that your board looks like there have been a number of repairs made, maybe even a missing (or broken off) diode in the bottom corner near the red transformer wires, it may be good to check on that issue first.

A few more positive things:
1) All of the component values are included on the schematics.
2) One of the schematics has test voltages listed, so  that should go a long way to help with troubleshooting.
3) Someone redrew a full schematic (further down the page) that is much more readable.

This should give you a very good start at repairing your unit. Comparing the listed test voltages should give you more clues as to the problem on your board.

If you do get stuck add a comment below this answer.

Comment: Hey Nedd the supply is a is a 220/240VAC version and its model number is the same.

Comment: What is strange is that there has never been a 1n4501in that second slot as long as i've had that supply and its output has always been 12vdc ish. So What type of board can I purchase to replace/modernise that supply 15vac with center tap must be able to be made to a better regulated supply?

Comment: @Love-to-Make - Without the second diode the supply becomes a half wave input, while not ideal it likely works well enough, just less efficient and potentially having a bit more ripple noise.  These days there are numerous better replacements for your type of 12V power supply, (much more efficient, smaller, lighter, etc).  I was assuming you wanted to go forward with repair of the existing unit.

Comment: so what would happen to the output if i moved diode into other slot? In theory it would use the other half of the wave so same output also if i add a diode to the board as you say there are more efficient ways of achieving this goal, so on that note I am not sure if i want to repair it or make a new board for it. If i did make a new board i would want max 14vdc out with a way of controlling the current output ideally 0-20A even if the transformer able to deliver that current. I'm sure there are ways of doing it maybe with a coil and a 555 or some thing

Comment: @Love-to-Make - Adding the other diode may make the old supply more efficient, however for your version there might be some other reason why it is only a half wave design. If it had worked as is I wouldn't bother installing it. The repairing may be rewarding to you, use the test voltages in one of the schematics for reference.  But overall the repair or replacement is your choice. These days much better supplies are available for a moderately low cost, (see Amazon, AliExpress, etc.).   Lastly, if the initial answer was satisfactory please tick the Accept box. This will close out the question.

Comment: Yes I have been looking but cannot find an appropriate (more efficient) replacement. Was kinda hoping someone on here would say "here are a few options" but nonetheless If i repair it my original question stands, what do i do about the transistor with heatsink on it. I cannot find that either and did find a replacement on rs I believe but I don't have any of those ones so thought the list of part numbers of items i do have could do but ..... don't wanna let the built in factory smoke out

Comment: First:  Here are some options for a new unit, (note that an Amazon page typically shows several other compatible items near the lower end of the page).  https://www.amazon.com/Pyramid-PS9KX-Universal-Regulated-Converter/dp/B0002BA570/ref=pd_sbs_328_img_1/135-6349427-0621604?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0002BA570&pd_rd_r=872513b9-b885-4976-9ae0-e85e92812eb6&pd_rd_w=qDR8n&pd_rd_wg=RudIu&pf_rd_p=5cfcfe89-300f-47d2-b1ad-a4e27203a02a&pf_rd_r=N67Z17QVKVAVF9XS19SW&psc=1&refRID=N67Z17QVKVAVF9XS19SW

Comment: Second:  The MJE3055 is a very common high power transistor.  Here is one from Jameco (0.79 US): https://www.jameco.com/z/MJE3055T-Major-Brands-Transistor-General-Purpose-BJT-NPN-60-Volt-10-Amp-3-Pin-3-Tab-TO-220-Ampb-Rail_25857.html?%20CID=GOOG&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIifSWzIGC5gIVAZSzCh3tXwayEAYYASABEgIspPD_BwE .  Digikey (0.84 US): https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicro/MJE3055T/497-2573-5-ND/603598&?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvMm_vYKC5gIVSpyzCh386Qe9EAQYASABEgL1CPD_BwE)  . Before replacing that specific part it would be good to do some checking to verify that is the main problem.

Comment: Sorry, I think you had an EU input requirement.  Here are a few others with 220VAC inputs:
https://www.amazon.com/ZTDM-Adjustable-Regulated-Stabilizer-Standard/dp/B01NACT99O/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=220vac+input+12vdc+output+desktop+power+supply&qid=1574570793&sr=8-9  (A little pricy but has voltage and current adjustments.)
A universal 120/230 version: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000NPT4TK/ref=emc_b_5_t  
One with UK plug: https://www.firstlightoptics.com/batteries-powerpacks/nevada-ps-08-6a-8a-regulated-linear-power-supply.html

Comment: Thanks for the links but unfortunately in the uk amazon seem to be out of stock for the power supplies. I Have been looking for a 15vac 0v 15vac replacement board but cant seem to find anything good enough and seeing as the separate components are so cheap i think i will try and fix existing board despite its efficiency drawbacks